# MS Word to DataGrid View WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, gridview

How to show data from word document to data grid view using interop in WPF?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Document doc = new Document();
object fileName = path;
object path = txbSelectedWordFile.Text;
// Define an object to pass to the API for missing parameters
object missing = System.Type.Missing;
doc = word.Documents.Open(ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

String read = string.Empty;
List<string> data = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < doc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
{
    string temp = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
    if (temp != string.Empty)
        data.Add(temp);
}

((_Document)doc).Close();
((_Application)word).Quit();
GridView1.DataSource = data;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

take a peek [googling....](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=wpf%20grid%20binding&oq=wpf%20grid%20binding&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i65l3j0.7039j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=wpf%20datagrid%20binding)

`GridView1.ItemsSource` is what you are looking...